What could be an alternative Infinispan cache API for Infinispan Tree Cache post Wildfly/jboss upgrade from version 10 to 26?
Recently, there was an upgrade from wildfly 10 to wildfly 26 in our application. Since then, we have faced problems with respect to cache implementation as we have been using Infinispan. In Infinispan, indexing configurations, index has been set to null which results in NPE in our code.
When tree cache is disabled, JVMCache has been used. However, we haven't found an alternative cache implementation for when tree cache is enabled.
Current versions being used -
Bundle-Name: Infinispan Tree API
Bundle-Version: 6.0.2.Final
Is there an existing alternative Infinispan Cache API to replace Infinispan Tree Cache?
Tried JVMCache when tree cache is disabled. Need alternative cache solutions for when tree cache is enabled, preferably using infinispan.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
